# touchstart evvent not firing in my paint view area appcelerator

Tags: javascript, dom-events, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

I am troubling to work with "Touchstart" event with my Appcelerator paint view area. It was working  perfectly with my previous Ti.Paint module (version 1.1) but by choosing latest module version, touchstart event does not firing. How can I fix my problem with latest module version of Ti.paint?

My code is :

```
main_view.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    alert('You have started to touch in your pain view');
});
```